# Equal weighted colors in fractional colorings

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I'm not sure if this is true, but does there always exist a fractional coloring of a graph $G$ that has a total weighting equal to the fractional chromatic number of $G$ such that the fractional coloring uses colors that are all equal in weight?

For example, the fractional chromatic number of the 5-cycle graph is $\frac{5}{2}$, and this can be attained by only using colors all of which that have a weight of $\frac{1}{2}$. But is this the case for any graph? If so, which textbook, paper etc. claims and proves this?

Comment: The answer to your question is a bit sensitive to your definition of "fractional coloring", so could you give the precise definition you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one possible definition of fractional coloring, to each independent set $I \subseteq V(G)$ we assign a weight $x_I$, such that at each vertex $v$ the total weight is at least $1$:
$$\sum_{I\, :\, v \in I} x_I \ge 1.$$
The idea is that if $x_I$ is nonzero, then there is a color that is put on all the vertices of $I$, but only with weight $x_I$. We try to minimize the total weight of all colors: the sum of $x_I$ over all $I$.

If we take this approach, then it may not be possible to make all nonzero $x_I$ equal. Consider the following graph:

[image: wheel-5]

Here, the only independent set containing the central vertex $0$ is the set $\{0\}$, so we must have $x_{\{0\}} = 1$. But if we try to use only weight $1$ for coloring the remaining vertices $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ then we end up finding the ordinary chromatic number, $4$. The fractional chromatic number of $\frac72$ can only be obtained by setting $x_{\{1,3\}} = x_{\{3,5\}} = x_{\{2,5\}} = x_{\{2,4\}} = x_{\{1,4\}} = \frac12$.

---

However, we can get around this problem if we are allowed to have "functionally identical" colors. If that's the case, then we find a common denominator, $q$, of all the $x_I$. (We know the $x_I$ are all rational because any linear program with rational coefficients has a rational optimal solution.) Now, if the solution above has $x_I = \frac{p_I}{q}$, then instead of having a single color on the vertices in $I$ with weight $x_I$, we have $p_I$ different colors on the vertices in $I$, each with weight $\frac{1}{q}$.

This does not change the total weight of all the colors; however, after we do this for all $I$, every color used has weight $\frac1q$, and so we get what we want.

Comment: You are using the same definition as what I have, although I'm hoping that we have the total weight of each vertex be equal to 1. If I am understanding you correctly, we can essentially take an optimal fractional coloring of a graph, find the common denominator $q$ of all the different weights, and then re-color the graph using the weight $1/q$ for each color and then add new colors with the same weight if needed and thus achieve an optimal fractional coloring using regular weighting.

Comment: So in the case of the 5-wheel graph, instead of coloring the center vertex with one color of weight 1, we can actually just find the common denominator of the optimal coloring, which is 2. By setting all weights to $\frac{1}{2}$ now, there is a possible fractional coloring of the 5-wheel graph using only weights $\frac{1}{2}$ and 7 colors.

Comment: Yes, exactly. (Also, we can make the constraint on total weight at each vertex be $=1$ or $\ge 1$, it doesn't matter; when we minimize the sum of weights, it will never make sense to make a vertex have weight $>1$.)